# ERROR minimum kernel version required for CoreDNS is 4.14.35 (UEKR5)

Tags: linux, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, coredns

I'm trying to setup High available Kubernetes cluster on ORL7 with kernel version as "3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64". All the pre requisites have been performed as per the link "https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52668_01/E88884/html/kube_ha_install_master.html".

Now when bringing up the cluster with the below command:
$ kubeadm-ha-setup up ~/ha.yaml

I'm getting below error:
[ERROR] minimum kernel version required for CoreDNS is 4.14.35 (UEKR5)

It worked for kubeadm (below command) but i want to know how to acheive the same in kubeadm-ha-setup.
$ kubeadm-ha-setup up ~/ha.yaml --feature-gates=CoreDNS=false

I can't upgade kernel version and using latest supported by our organization.

Comment: Apologies for the typo, we are using OEL7 version of linux

Comment: You can edit your post by clicking the *Edit* link in the lower left-hand corner of the question.

Comment: Hi, [Ankit Chitransh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6831136/ankit-chitransh) what is the  result of your investigation?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that  you can't. As per documentation ["Requirements to Use Oracle Container Services for use with Kubernetes"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52668_01/E88884/html/requirements-bmc.html) and ["Replacement of KubeDNS with CoreDNS"](https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/announcing-oracle-container-services-1112-for-use-with-kubernetes%22)

Note:

> A future version of Oracle Linux Container Services for use with Kubernetes will migrate existing single master clusters from KubeDNS to CoreDNS. CoreDNS requires an Oracle Linux 7 Update 5 image or later with the Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel Release 5 (UEK R5).
>
> Existing Oracle Linux Container Services for use with Kubernetes 1.1.9 installations may already run on an Oracle Linux 7 Update 3 image, with Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel Release 4 (UEK R4), but you must upgrade your environment to permit future product upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

```
kubeadm-ha-setup up ~/ha.yaml --feature-gates=CoreDNS=false
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.
It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also Explaining entirely code-based answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers